# Why would this code produce a segfault?

Tags: xml, json, haskell, segmentation-fault, aeson

I am trying to write a module that parses xml from an api, strips out some information, and prints the result as json, but I've hit a hiccup at the printing step. If I print shows I do indeed see that the correct data is there, however, the call which should transform the records into json, `encode shows`, produces a segfault.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LazyByteString

openUrl :: String -> IO String
openUrl url = getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest url)

composeSearch :: String -> String
composeSearch query = "http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/search.php?show=" ++ urlEncode query

searchShow :: String -> IO String
searchShow query = openUrl $ composeSearch query

data TvShow = TvShow { showName, showId :: String } deriving (Show)

getShow = deep (isElem >>> hasName "show") >>>
    proc x -> do
        name <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "name")  -< x
        id <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "showid") -< x 
        returnA -< TvShow { showName = name, showId = id }

instance ToJSON TvShow where
    toJSON (TvShow name id) = object ["name" .= name, "id" .= id]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    results <- searchShow "Always Sunny" 
    shows <- runX (readString [ withValidate  no ] results >>> getShow)
    putStrLn (LazyByteString.unpack (encode shows))
```

**Edit:** As user1891025 has pointed out, This may be an issue with my machine or package versions.

- System: Ubuntu 11.04 32bit
- Aeson v0.6.1.0
- GHC v7.2.1

This question is getting increasing specific, so I will take it to irc, but if anyone has any assistance please let me know!

Comment: It works for me.  You may want to post your system info, package versions, and error messages if they exist.

Comment: I think you are correct. I've tried a posted example that also used `encode` but it also segfaulted. Aeson (presumably) seems to dislike my machine. :)

Comment: What flags do you use to compile the code? Could be issues with e.g. the LLVM backend on your chipset.

Comment: I used `ghc --make TvGenius.hs` to compile then just ran the executable with `./TvGenius`

Comment: No crash on Debian 64bit, with the same GHC version (Ubuntu uses Debian’s packages), but aeson 0.6.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aeson's `encode` function calls `encodeUtf8` from the `Data.Text` package. That function uses `unsafeDupablePerformIO` and other unsafe functions to poke around in memory. That's possibly where the segfault happens.

See the code [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.3.1/doc/html/src/Data-Text-Encoding.html).